# is this possible in Excel, with pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a data set that looks like this
[image]

Is it possible to get a single pivot table that do the summary like below, basically counting the No. of users who has replied Yes/No for Option A/B

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get a single pivot table that do the summary

**No**, your data is already in kind of a pivot view, applying another pivot won't work well.

Instead you can use a formula to count answers:
`=COUNTIF(INDEX($B:$C,0,MATCH($E2,$B$1:$C$1,0)),F$1)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in PivotTable, but you can use Power Query to get the result:

1. Select the **Range** and go to **Data- Get & Transform Data**- **From Table/Range**- open **Power Query Editor**:
   [image]
2. Select **OPTION A column and OPTION B column**- go to **Transform**- select **Unpivot Columns**:
   [image]
3. Select **Value Column**- go to **Transform**- **Pivot Column**- **Value Column** select **User**- under **Advanced options** select **Count(ALL)**- Close and Load
   [image]
4. You can add data in source table and **Refresh** the Result Table it will update automatically:
   [image]